# Efficient way to find mean value of bits across columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a `df` with `N` columns and `M` rows, where each entry is a 8-bit integer. N and M are very large. Let's take an example with `N=5` and `M=10`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))

>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  2  4  8  9  9
1  1  1  1  1  6
2  9  7  5  2  2
3  8  1  8  6  4
4  8  6  7  9  5
5  9  6  5  9  9
6  1  3  2  3  3
7  6  5  9  9  5
8  6  5  2  9  3
9  1  7  9  7  1
```

I want to find the average of each of the 8 bits across columns and create a new column for each.

In our example, this would result in the following (only shown for the first row):

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  Bit7 Bit6 Bit5 Bit4  Bit3    Bit2    Bit1    Bit0
0  2  4  8  9  9   0    0    0    0   3/5=0.6 1/5=0.2 1/5=0.2 2/5=0.4
1  1  1  1  1  6
2  9  7  5  2  2
3  8  1  8  6  4
4  8  6  7  9  5
5  9  6  5  9  9
6  1  3  2  3  3
7  6  5  9  9  5
8  6  5  2  9  3
9  1  7  9  7  1
```

`Bit0` column is created by averaging the LSBs `{0 (from col a), 0 (from col b), 0 (from col c), 1 (from col d), 0 (from col e)}`, `Bit1` column by the average of `{1,0,0,0,0}`, and so on until `Bit7` column corresponding to the MSBs of the columns.

What is an efficient way of achieving this, keeping in mind that `N` and `M` are large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to solve this other than just finding the average one bit at a time. [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is a good way to perform an operation on the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=5
M=10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, M, (M, N)), columns=list('abcde'))


for bitNum in range(8):
    df[f'Bit{bitNum}'] = df.apply(lambda row : (sum([1 & (row[i] >> bitNum)  for i in range(N)])), axis=1)

for bitNum in range(8):
    df[f'Bit{bitNum}'] = df[f'Bit{bitNum}'].apply(lambda x : float(x)/N)
```

You'll notice that the code above does the division to get the average after all of the sums have completed. That was a weird issue I faced when coding this. If you try to add the division by $N$ in the first lambda function, it will complain that you are performing `<<` on a float and comparing to an integer. However, if I printed the `df` row and then tried again it worked... perhaps someone can explain. Regardless, the answer above works I believe!

EDIT: If you are using Python 3, you can skip the float conversion in the second loop.

Comment: Last line could simply be `df[f'Bit{bitNum}'] = df[f'Bit{bitNum}'] / float(N)`

Comment: Note that python f-strings only work after version 3.6

Comment: Simply replace `f'Bit{bitnum}'` with `'Bit{}'.format(bitNum)` if your python version is 3.x where `x<6`. If you are using Python2, `"Bit%i" % bitNum`  will work

Comment: @BryceKille This is a little faster than the apply function I am using currently. Overall, this is pretty slow when compared to the other tricks that Pandas/Python supports. Will keep the thread open for a day more and if no better method is answered, will mark as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I agree that it doesn’t seem as optimized as possible, I’ll think some more in the meantime as well (:

Comment: I imagine there is something to be said about the cache performance. If N and M are large enough, the solution above won’t be great. In that case, we’d want to work one row at a time, instead of one bit column at a time.